# How to get spring boot return value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I try to call API. API return boolean value. I need to get that value inside angularjs code. I tried with many ways. But I couldn't get my answer.

Angular JS code

```
var url = some url;

        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }

        $http.get(url, config).then(function(response) {

            if(response.data==true){
                $scope.result = "Username already exist";
            }
            else{
                $scope.result = '';
            }

        }, function error(response) {
            $scope.postResultMessage = "Error Status: " +  
            response.statusText;
        });
```

Spring boot class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/regForm/getUserByUsername/{username}")
public boolean getUserByUsername(@PathVariable String username) {

    boolean value;
    User customers = userRepository.findByUserName(username);
    if(username.equals(customers.getUserName())){
        value =  true;
    }
    else{
        value =  false;
    }
    return  value;
}
```

I use alert to get response.data .

```
alert(response.data);
```

Then alert show bellow output.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should at first check the response object and then start comparing. 
BTW what is the response object can you also post that in your question.

Comment: Thanks your  comment. Updated my question

Comment: I am still unclear. Please provide a screen shot of the network tab and check the API response rather than alerting it. Also if possible provide a js fiddle so that I can also try to debug.